# How to use adobe edge animations in website?

Tags: html, animation, adobe-edge

I want use adobe edge animation in my website . I add required files into page head .Adobe edge worked with this div tag only

```
<div id="Stage" class="EDGE-7942973">   </div>
```

and add another elements dynamically into it .I test and understand that if this div tag placed into another  tags animations don't run. . How to fix this problem?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <title>Untitled</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="advertisement_anim_edgePreload.js"></script>
    <style>
        .edgeLoad-EDGE-7942973 { visibility:hidden; }
    </style>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">


    <div id="Stage" class="EDGE-7942973">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version you are using? cc 2015?

Comment: Adobe Edge animate cc 2014

Comment: In cc 2015 you can put `Stage` div what ever you want & animation works perfectly. If it's not work for cc 2014 you can call animation containing file via `iframe`.

Comment: Can you write code for use iframe?

Comment: I just tested for cc 2014. it's working fine.

Comment: My html codes is like question. If your codes like my codes How to use in website?

Comment: Yes my `html` generated from cc 2015 like yours but from cc 2014 not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep adobe edge published files in a folder `folder_name` and place following `tag` in your html file whatever you want. Don't forget to change `folder_name` & `file_name`.

```
<iframe src="folder_name/file_name.html"></iframe>
```

Set `height` & `width` of `iframe` according to stage size.